# NSMutable array exception

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray

I am getting data from web service and displayed it in a tableview and at button click which is at tableview i am storing data id in nsmutablearray . Then i am comparing  clicked data id which is stored in nsmutable array with web service data in   cellForRowAtIndexPath function.

Error:

At code comparing in tableview, exception index not found.

At button click i tried these all::::

```
 [myidmutablearray addObject:[[webservicedata valueForKey:@"id"]objectAtIndex:clickedButtonIndexPath.row]]; 

 [myidmutablearray insertObject:[webservicedata valueForKey:@"id"] atIndex:clickedButtonIndexPath.row];

 [myidmutablearray replaceObjectAtIndex:clickedButtonIndexPath.row withObject:[webservicedata valueForKey:@"id"]];
```

At CellForRowAtIndexPath I tried this,

```
    if([myidmutablearray count]!=0)

    {
    if([[webservicedata valueForKey:@"id"] containsObject:[myidmutablearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]])

        NSLog(@"not empty");
    }

  else
        NSLog(@"empty");
```

Comment: i cant understand what you really want to do, its confusing me

Comment: if([[webservicedata valueForKey:@"id"] containsObject:[myidmutablearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]])          It gives exception here index not found why is that ??

Comment: Simple  ,    At button click i use one of those line of code to save id then in tableview i am comparing stored id with ids from webservice, got it sir ?

Comment: assume that you have 20 records in table and you clicked at 19th data in table view, then id 19 store in array, actually there is only on data in array and you give the index of 19 of table view .... then obviously it cant find index

Comment: there is only on data in array , what does it mean ?   NSmutable array  can make it's size accordingly na ?

Comment: you can not add record at desired position first record always added to 0 index next is on 1 and so on

Comment: you can use NSDictionary for fulfill your purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSMutableArray is not an array with an indefinite number of entries, whose index you can assign.

As you add objects to an NSMutableArray, the first entry added will be at index 0.  No matter what index you give to it when adding.

I think What you really want is an NSDictionary, with the key as an NSNumber made from the indexpath.row.  Then you can retrieve it later using an NSNumber again.

When saving, do something like this:

```
//defining somewhere 
NSMutableDictionary *myIdMutableDictionary;


//then in the button click:
[myIdMutableDictionary setObject:[webservicedata valueForKey:@"id"] forKey:@(indexPath.row)];


//then later to check it, you test value would be in this:
[[myIdMutableDictionary objectForKey:@(indexPath.row)
```